# Unable to resolve symbol: Workflow.EntityLogicalName

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I think I'm missing a using statement:

```C#
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

Workflow.EntityLogicalName;
```

Extra info:

- I'm using the crm 2013 SDK.
- Workflow is recognized and is in the **Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities** reference.
- I'm trying to get this sample to work: http://www.mscrmconsultant.com/2012/06/run-ondemand-workflow-from-c-code-in.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have added following references:

`Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk`

`Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow`

If you have these references then Generate the Entity Wrapper for workflows using `CRM Explorer`. and then replace

```C#
Workflow.EntityLogicalName
```

with

```C#
Entities.Workflow.EntityLogicalName
```

Comment: They are referenced in the project, as well as in the code file.

Comment: @DemianKasier I hope you have generated the Entity Wrapper using CRM explorer. If you have generated the Entity Wrapper then use as `Entities.Workflow.EntityLogicalName`.

Comment: that was it! Since i'm new to crm I didn't know about that. Pls edit it in your answer and I'll accept it.